# Import daily CSV Files To Standard Excel Worksheet Locations

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import

I want to import csv files to my own workbook. Now it creates a new workbook every time. I want the data within my csv files to go in the different sheets. Only I want the data set to 11 standard sheets cause I have 11 teams (Team A, Team B etc.). This does currently work as it creates a new workbook with 11 sheets.

I have an Excel file set up that I want to use for a project.
In this case there are several teams that export data daily to csv files.
Now, I want to import these files to my active workbook where each team will have it's own worksheet. The CSV data files will need to be imported by using a button. Then the csv data will go into the same workbook.

I found the following code on the web and it works good! The only issue with this way is that it creates a new workbook every time. Then I have to copy the data from the new generated workbook (the data per team in sheets) to my own workbook.

This copy pasting is as you can imagine quite annoying at the moment. I hope there is anyone that is good at programming and could possibly help me :) ? The code that I currently use to Import the data to a random generated workbook is as following:

```
Sub DataImporteren()


    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sDelimiter = ","

    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="CSV Files to Open")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    x = 1
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbTemp.Close (False)
    wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    x = x + 1

    While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        With wkbAll
            wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
        End With
        x = x + 1
    Wend

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

So at the end what I need help with:
Standard workbook where I have my overview. With calculations and formulas to compare the imported data. (already have this working)

Import the data to this standard workbook instead of a this macro creating a new workbook every time.

For each team in (standard csv files) my workbook a standard sheet. CSV file: "Team A" gets imported to worksheet Team A every time I import the new updated Team A csv file etc.

I hope someone can help me as this would save me lots of time copy pasting.

Comment: Important information is missing: Should the data coming in be appended or replace the data already in the workbook? Should information (formulas, for example) already in the workbook be retained? If yes, how is this to be identified? What kind of VBA background do you have?

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister, the data coming in should replace the data that's already my sheet. My idea is that I have 12 worksheets.
One of them is a sheet which compares the updated data from the other 11 sheets. These 11 sheets are Team A, Team B etc. Now using thecode I get the data in a new workbook per csv file (named per team) in 11 worksheets. 
Instead of a new file with 11 sheets I want the updated sheets to overwrite the 11 team sheets I have in my workbook. 
Furthermore my VBA skills are quite basic, I'm still at school and had basic VBA lessons only nothing detailed like this sadly.

Comment: Are you sure this code is creating a new workbook for each file? It looks to me like it's opening the csv file and *copying* the content to sheets 1 through x of the active workbook. (And that line of code needs to be near the beginning, before `FileToOpen`.)

Comment: Hi @cindymeister yes it creates a new empty book with   for each csv file a worksheet.

Comment: Yes, but it should be closing these without saving, after the contents are copied to the current workbook, from the look of the code.

Comment: Oke and how could i perhaps copy them to the active workbook that Im working on? so that each file has its own standard sheet? :) @cindymeister

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in a previous comment that the one line of code needs to be moved. Also, the start value for x should be changed from 1 to 2 (probably) so that the pasting starts on the second sheet.

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister I've tried to move the text. But, then I get an error while running the code. Could you maybe specify which part of the code has to be moved exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. There are a number of changes to the code in the question.

- The target Workbook is set near the beginning, before the files are opened, which would change the "active" workbook. This way, there's no confusion.
- The entire copying is in a `For...Next` loop. As far as I can tell, there's no reason for one execution, then a loop. I've used `For...Next` so that the `x` increments automatically.
- The actual problem asked in the question is due to not specifying the *target* where the content of the csv file should be inserted. If no target range is specified, the data is placed in a new workbook. The target range is therefore set to the Worksheet(x + 1) in the target workbook; the `UsedRange` of the in-coming data sheet is copied (instead of the entire worksheet) - this places the data at the top left of the target worksheet.
- `x + 1` is used since the data should go to the second and following worksheets.
- The data sheet is only closed after the copy and insertion and the variable set to Nothing. This worked more reliably in my tests.

As it stands, Excel will query whether to over-write the existing sheet content when new data is brought in. If this is not wanted, insert a line that deletes the UsedRange of each worksheet before the data is inserted.

```
Sub DataImporteren()
    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Long
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim rngDestination As Range
    Dim sDelimiter As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sDelimiter = "|"
    x = 1

    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="CSV Files to Open")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    For x = 1 To UBound(FilesToOpen)
        'Start at second worksheet
        Set rngDestination = wkbAll.Worksheets(x + 1).Range("A1")
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        Set wsData = wkbTemp.Worksheets(1)
        wsData.UsedRange.Copy rngDestination

        wkbAll.Worksheets(x + 1).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
          Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
          TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
          ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
          Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
          Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
          Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter

        wkbTemp.Close False
        Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Next

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @cindymeister I've tried the code above. but it didn't seem to work for me. I now have a other code but this one has a bug that it leaves a new workbook with one imported file open. The rest seems to work? By the way how can I send you this code? Cause the comment section is to small?